# How to use XML validation for checkboxlist and select in Struts 2 on JSP?

Tags: java, forms, validation, jsp, struts2

This is my jsp file:

```xml
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags" %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Company Data</title>
</head>
<body>
<center><h3>Company Data</h3></center>
<s:form action="companyData" validate="true">
    <s:textfield label="Name" key="companyName" />
    <s:textfield label="ISIN" key="companyISIN" />
    <s:checkboxlist list="exchangesList" label="Exchange" name="exchange" />
    <s:select list="sectorsList" label="Sector" name="sector" />
    <s:checkboxlist list="shareholdersList" label="Shareholders" name="shareholders" />
    <s:submit />
</s:form>
</body>
</html>
```

Here, `shareholdersList` is an `ArrayList<String>` and `shareholders` is a `String`.

This is my action-validation file:

```xml
<!DOCTYPE validators PUBLIC 
"-//OpenSymphony Group//XWork Validator 1.0.2//EN"
"http://struts.apache.org/dtds/xwork-validator-1.0.2.dtd">
<validators>
<field name="companyName">
    <field-validator type="required">
        <message>You must enter some name for companyName</message>
    </field-validator>
</field>

<field name="companyISIN">
    <field-validator type="required">
        <message>You must enter some id for companyISIN</message>
    </field-validator>
</field>

<field name="exchange">
    <field-validator type="fieldexpression">
        <param name="expression">
            <![CDATA[ isDoNotCheck() ? true : (exchange != null && !exchange.isEmpty()) ]]>
            <!-- OR -->
            <!-- isDoNotCheck() ? true : !object.field.isEmpty() -->
        </param>
        <message>You must check some checkboxes for exchange</message>
    </field-validator>
</field>

<field name="shareholders">
    <field-validator type="fieldexpression">
        <message>You must check some checkboxes for shareholders</message>
    </field-validator>
</field>      
</validators>
```

Here is the screenshot on submitting the form:

[image]

Validations for textboxes are working fine but for checkboxlist it's not working at all. I want the checkboxlist validation so that the user must select at least one of the checkbox from the list. What should be done to correct the code?

Also, I have a similar select list instead of the checkboxlist in some other jsp, so how can that list be validated too. I found many things on internet but nothing worked till now.

Comment: Change to developer mode to see more exceptions, if you have exceptions parsing expression, please post it to the question.

Comment: Which exact version of S2 are you using? Are you sure that `shareholders` and `exchange` are String-s and have proper getters/setters?

Comment: 2.3.24. Yep. The logic behind them is running absolutely fine. It's just the validation that is creating problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try with the following code:

```xml
<field name="exchange">
    <field-validator type="fieldexpression">
        <param name="expression">exchange.length() > 0</param>
        <message><![CDATA[ You must check some checkboxes for exchange ]]></message>
    </field-validator>
</field>

<field name="shareholders">
    <field-validator type="fieldexpression">
        <param name="expression">shareholders.length() > 0</param>
        <message><![CDATA[ You must check some checkboxes for shareholders ]]></message>
    </field-validator>
</field>
```

If it works, start adding your custom conditions (`isDoNotCheck()`...).

Otherwise, use a non-field validator, that works for sure:

```xml
<validator type="fieldexpression">
    <param name="fieldname">exchange</param>
    <param name="expression"><![CDATA[exchange.length() > 0]]></param>
    <message><![CDATA[ You must check some checkboxes for exchange ]]></message>
</validator>

<validator type="fieldexpression">
    <param name="fieldname">shareholders</param>
    <param name="expression"><![CDATA[shareholders.length() > 0]]></param>
    <message><![CDATA[ You must check some checkboxes for shareholders ]]></message>
</validator>
```

Comment: both things are not working. Nothing is printed on the form or the console on submitting the empty form for the checkboxes.

Comment: I'm using the default interceptor stack only as I'm a beginner to Struts 2.

Comment: Really weird. Re-check everything for typos, missing getter / setter, etc... also try adding some log

Comment: Please do check the XML file for me. Here's the link: http://pastebin.com/7hbmaiFM

Comment: Use 1.0.3 instead of 1.0.2, and **use [`requiredstring` validator](https://struts.apache.org/docs/requiredstring-validator.html) for String field, instead of `required`**... basically the only things that should work are those that are not working :D Try with this two changes, and if it still doesn't work, try with non-field validator, my second example. If it still doesn't work, edit your question describing exactly what you tried and the result you got, and post your struts.xml and web.xml. Good luck ;)

Answer (score 0):

Use the following code.The value of checkbox List is stored as a string.Hence,you can use requiredstring.

```
  <field name="exchange">
    <field-validator type="requiredstring">
       <message>Please select exchange type</message>
    </field-validator>
  </field>

 <field name="shareholders">
   <field-validator type="requiredstring">
      <message>Please select shareholders</message>
   </field-validator>
 </field>
```